# Utilising the output of two previous gulp streams

Tags: javascript, stream, gulp

I would like to take the result of a CSS processing step `getCss`, and a JS processing step `getJs`, then use these two results to create a file named `index.html`, which is the result of inlining the processed CSS and processed JS into a template named `index-template.html`.

Can someone help me better understand how I can achieve this?

This is what I have so far...

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    eventStream.merge(getCss.bind(gulp), getJs.bind(gulp))
        .pipe(inlineJsAndCss.bind(gulp));
});

function getCss() {
    return this.src(options.lessGlob)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(minifyCss());
}

function getJs() {
    return this.src(options.jsGlob)
        .pipe(uglify());
}

function inlineJsAndCss() {
    // Take the CSS and the JS generated by 
    // previous steps and inline them into 
    // index-template.html
    //...
    .pipe(this.dest('index.html'));
}
```

**Edit:** is storing the result of the intermediate steps in memory, and then creating a stream from this, this the canonical way to achieve this?

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/make-stream-from-buffer.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `eventStream.merge` is not required.

Simply output the result of the CSS and the JS processing steps into a region of memory visible by the final step, and then configure the gulp dependencies accordingly.

Something like so:

```
const sharedMemory = {};
gulp.task('css', partial(getCss, sharedMemory));
gulp.task('js', partial(getJs, sharedMemory));
gulp.task('inline', ['css', 'js'], partial(inline, sharedMemory));
gulp.task('build', ['replace']);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```